# How to install certificate in ECS Fargate Container to enable TLS all the way to container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

My objective is to enable ssl/tls on AWS ECS Fargate container itself and this is company's requirement. I am aware of ssl termination at ALB and let ALB communicate with tasks on http. However in my case I am required to take it a step further and enable TLS on container, doing this way traffic would be encrypted all the way to my container.

I have gone through tons of posts from google but, unfortunately not able to find any solution that I can implement.

I am using VS 2022 to build my .net core mvc solution on framework 6.0. On my locahost my visual studio is kind enough to ask me if I want to enable SSL and creates self signed certificate for me, and allows me to run my solution under docker profile, and allows me to access via https://localhost...

All good so far, just to note here is that I am not doing any thing extra to make this website available via https://

Now, I build my docker image and deployed it to AWS and running this under fargate, and here I took ip address of running task and try to access it using https:// shows me message (in google chrome)  "this site does not have a certificate"

Next, from my googling I found somewhere to pass environment variables as below and which I am doing

```
aspnetcore_environment=development
aspnetcore_urls=https://+:443;http://+:80
```

after adding above to my "Task Rivision" - and creating new service using this task definition - would not even let my task run with error (cloudwatch logs) - "*System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.*"

How to tackle this ?

Comment: Leave your container on 80 THEN attach your certificates to a ALB, attach this ALB to ECS services

Comment: @J-JacquesM thank you for your response. Requirement here is to enable TLS/HTTPS at the container level, if I go with SSL termination at ALB level, traffic between ALB and Container will still be un-encrypted.